# Comparing field value with count of occurrences

Tags: mysql

i dont exactly know how write down this query,
so im asking your guys and gals help.

so, i have a table the contains something like:

**COLUMNS**
id,keyword,pages

what i basicly need is to get all the rows where pages!=count(keyword)
this is basicly how i tried to do it anyway.

so it should be really simple, return all rows, where the keyword count does not equal the pages column value.

so, if for example the data is like this :

```
ROW A: 1, aaa, 3
ROW B: 4, aaa, 3
ROW C: 5, aaa, 3
ROW D: 5, aac, 100
```

with an example as above, 
only ROW D will be returned since rows a,b,c PAGES (3) match the keyword count.

any help will welcome.
thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution without a subquery. This will work filne in Mysql, but for more strict SQL's you need to add some aggregate functios.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM mytable AS a
    LEFT JOIN mytable AS b
        ON b.keyword = a.keyword
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(b.id) != a.pages
```

Also use indexes like these:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON mytable (keyword);
CREATE INDEX myindex2 ON mytable (pages);
```

Comment: Shees, this MySQL gives me the SQL-creeps! :-)

Comment: hi vbence.
i tried your solution ( which is similar to what i tried to do ) 
but it gives an error on b.*, which is the same problem i had with my own code.

Comment: @Rephael Try this version. If it does not work, then you have to SELECT the `COUNT(b.id)` AS an other field, then HAVING willdefinitely work on it.

Comment: i will mark your query as answered, since you were the first to answer and you query is looking similar to the one i started to write myself before posting this question.
even due, i think that half an answer is reserved for lukas for the index information.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from table t1
where t1.pages <> (select count(*)
                     from table t2
                    where t1.keyword = t2.keyword)
```

But that's a a pretty slow query. Just to give you an idea...

Comment: It would be a good idea to: `CREATE INDEX myindex ON mytable (keyword)` and `CREATE INDEX myindex2 ON mytable (pages)`

Comment: @vbence: `myindex2` is not really necessary as MySQL will probably choose to run a nested loop for the inner select. But I agree on `myindex`

Comment: @Lukas Eder: You're probably right, but with indexes I subscribe to a "better safe than sorry" attitude :)

Comment: @vbence: That might be true for a small database, but for a big one, the index itself may be the performance bottleneck, depending on the operations you run against your tables. I don't know about MySQL, but indexes can be a nightmare too, with Oracle. In any case, I guess the above table will tend to become rather big, and indexes should be chosen wisely, as I'd expect a high data fluctuation (lots of inserts/updates). So one index too many might severly slow down the system...

Comment: This solution works as suggested ( slowwww ;P ) 
just want to know what is the fuss about indexes,
since i do have id as index, and the datatable is not to use a lot of inserts/updates.

Comment: @Rephael, I suggest you read about the "fuss" here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html. Since you will have a "self join" on the `keyword` column, an index will immediately accelerate the above query by several orders of magnitude. Trust me. Just run `CREATE INDEX ON table(keyword)` and try again

Comment: well guyz,
i tried adding an index as suggested,
i run the query this morning, came back from work just now to see it is still processing it.
i think i will skip making an index.